# Error in creating MS SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "SECURITY"."UPDATE_REFS_P" 
( 
in pIdProcessExec bigint, 
in pProcessDate DATE, 
in pDebugMode integer default 0, 
in pCallingInterface varchar(200) default 'Manual', 
out pCheckResult integer 
)
```

The error is:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near the keyword
>   'OR'.

When I remove the "OR REPLACE", the error is

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure UPDATE_REFS_P, Line 3 [Batch
>   Start Line 0] Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'in'.

Comment: That's not T-SQL - the dialect of SQL used by SQL Server, its from a different database entirely.  Your going to need to rewrite it.

Comment: The syntax for SQL Server would be `CREATE OR ALTER`, however, as @AlexK. has pointed out, the rest is still not SQL Server either. SQL Server uses brackets (`[]`) for quoting objects, not double quotes (`"`), and variables/parameters start with an at symbol (`@`) and don't being the declaration with `in`. I have no idea what language that is meant to be.

Comment: That was Oracle..

Comment: @That was Oracle.@ Msg 156 this ms sql error message

Comment: Although this part of the procedure definition is easy to rewrite with some adjustments, Oracle and SQL Server are very different when it comes to most (imperative, procedural) statements that you would find in stored procedures. If this is not an exercise in writing a new procedure, but an attempt to port an existing one, you'll probably need someone well-versed in both database systems.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE "SECURITY"."UPDATE_REFS_P" 
 @pIdProcessExec bigint, 
 @pProcessDate DATE, 
 @pDebugMode integer default 0, 
 @pCallingInterface varchar(200) default 'Manual', 
 @pCheckResult integer OUT
```

OR

```
ALTER PROCEDURE "SECURITY"."UPDATE_REFS_P" 
 @pIdProcessExec bigint, 
 @pProcessDate DATE, 
 @pDebugMode integer default 0, 
 @pCallingInterface varchar(200) default 'Manual', 
 @pCheckResult integer OUT
```

Another variant

```
IF OBJECT_ID(SECURITY.UPDATE_REFS_P) IS NOT NULL
 DROP PROC SECURITY.UPDATE_REFS_P

GO
CREATE PROCEDURE "SECURITY"."UPDATE_REFS_P" 
 @pIdProcessExec bigint, 
 @pProcessDate DATE, 
 @pDebugMode integer default 0, 
 @pCallingInterface varchar(200) default 'Manual', 
 @pCheckResult integer OUT
```

Comment: What you are trying to say??

Comment: Сorrect syntax!!

Comment: In SQL Server 2016 SP1 and later, one can use [`CREATE OR ALTER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql)

Comment: And what does `in pIdProcessExec bigint,` mean? That isn't SQL Server syntax.

Answer (score 0):

**Explanations:**

Your statement syntax is for PL/SQL (Oracle). Error message is from MS SQL Server. If you want to translate this statement into T-SQL (MS SQL Server), you must use this (`SECURITY` must be your schema name or use `dbo` as schema name):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [SECURITY].[UPDATE_REFS_P]
    @pIdProcessExec bigint, 
    @pProcessDate date, 
    @pDebugMode integer = 0, 
    @pCallingInterface varchar(200) = 'Manual',
    @pCheckResult integer OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    ...
END
```

and

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [SECURITY].[UPDATE_REFS_P]
    @pIdProcessExec bigint, 
    @pProcessDate date, 
    @pDebugMode integer = 0, 
    @pCallingInterface varchar(200) = 'Manual',
    @pCheckResult integer OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    ...
END
```

Extended syntax [OR ALTER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) applies to Azure SQL Database and SQL Server (starting with SQL Server 2016 (13.x) SP1).

**Working example:**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[UPDATE_REFS_P]
    @pIdProcessExec bigint, 
    @pProcessDate date, 
    @pDebugMode integer = 0, 
    @pCallingInterface varchar(200) = 'Manual',
    @pCheckResult integer OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    -- Default value as resultset
    SELECT @pCallingInterface AS [TEXT]

    -- Output parameter value
    SELECT @pCheckResult = 123

    --
    RETURN 0
END
```